# Warranty claim on thermal cracking of asphalt shingles?

Tags: roof, shingles

Two questions really:

1. How bad is this thermal cracking? Is the roof shot / need replacing based on this issue?

[image]

and...

[image]

2. Given that this roof is fairly new - 3 years (located in Arizona), is it worth looking into a possible warranty claim? I'm still retrieving install documentation from seller (not my house yet). Though, they claim it is recent and warranty exists. Also, is of worthy note that there are no soffit vents? Does that matter/potentially the cause? Large gable vents exist, but that's it. No attic fan either.

Done quite a few homes now, never seen this issue on a roof. Any information is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is that an overlay job? Judging by the crack layout I'd have guessed that there was a layer under this one. If so, the warranty is out the window.

Comment: @isherwood
Good question and input! It did not look like an overlay, I'll have to go back and validate or wait for seller to give us roof work statement.

Comment: + isherwood I was thinking the same that is a large hump for a singe layer of shingles/ but I haven't roofed in Az. the extended heat may cause more issue than I see. There can be a ridge vent a little harder to spot because it is the entire ridge. ridge vents have small air channels under each side of the ridge cap and a slot is cut in the roofing to allow ventilation

Comment: Definitely no ridge vent.